# Can I add an NVMe SSD to my motherboard?

Tags: laptop, motherboard, ssd, pcie, upgrade

I have a [TOSHIBA P50-C-10G](https://il.dynabook.com/en/discontinued-products/satellite-p50-c-10g/) laptop. and want to upgrade the internal drive from HDD to SSD. I am considering either SATA or NVMe, but I'm not sure if my computer has support for NVMe. I opened it up and found what looks to be a motherboard port for the NVMe card, but it doesn't have the dock to put the card in it. The pictures are down below. Is it possible to somehow add the dock and would it even be supported?

[image: NVME port 1]
[image: NVME port 2]

P.S. If there is a better forum or stackexchange site, please let me know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Additional logic is required in the motherboard's chipset which your Toshiba does not have (after a review of its specifications, linked in your question above). So, it will not work.

Also, PCIe SSDs AKA NVMe have a slightly different connector than SATA SSDs as shown below.

[image: NVMe M.2 SSD]
[image: SATA M.2 SSD]

[image: M.2 connector types]

I can't see an M.2 connector in the photo, so I looked for other photos, and [found a wider and sharper photo](https://laptopmedia.com/highlights/inside-toshiba-satellite-p50-c-disassembly-internal-photos-and-upgrade-options/) from [this page](https://laptopmedia.com/highlights/inside-toshiba-satellite-p50-c-disassembly-internal-photos-and-upgrade-options/).  There's no connector for any M.2 drive, so you must use a 2.5" SATA SSD to replace the original [Toshiba MQ02ABD100H HDD](https://www.notebookcheck.net/Toshiba-MQ02ABD100H-Benchmarked.440721.0.html). Here's a [video showing how to open it up](https://images.app.goo.gl/QvdcJkenJdVm6TUM7).

What you had circled to the right above the ribbon cable connecting the motherboard to an i/o daughterboard is where an M.2 connector might have gone, as evidenced by the post which looks like the right size to hold a fastening screw for the left side of an M.2 card, but there's no connector for it at the left side on the circuit board. It's very common to reuse circuit boards for different models and only put the connectors on the board which are required for a specific model.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. So what is the port circled in yellow for?

Comment: That's where a connector might go, but it was left off. It's very common to reuse circuit boards on different designs and only put the connectors on the board which are required for a specific model.